# Best way to dynamically add items from an array to an object as new values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
let obj = [
    {"id": "1"},
    {"id": "2"},
    {"id": "3"}
]
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

obj = addAtoO(arr, obj); // expected outcome: obj = [{"id": "1", "text": "a"}, {"id": "2", "text": "b"}, {}]
```

In words: dynamically add values from an array to an object as new values.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
const addAtoO = (a, o) => {
    o.map((i) => {
        console.log(Object.keys(i));
        // a.forEach((e) => {
        //     console.log(e);
        // });
        i['text'] = 'something'; // just add text for testing
    });
    return o;
};

obj = addAtoO(arr, obj);
console.log('result:');
console.log(obj);
```

But it seems like there must be a better way.

> Thank you so much guys. All your solutions are correct. I had to mark one so I picked the one that is the closest to this specific question.

Comment: yes that's what `id` does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using `addAtoO` suggests that you don't care about altering the original objects. If that's the case, then a simple `forEach` will do:

```
const addAtoO = (arr, obj) => arr.forEach((t, i) => obj[i].text = t);
```

`addToO` alters the original array of objects `obj`, so it doesn't return anything.

**Example:**

```js
const addAtoO = (arr, obj) => arr.forEach((t, i) => obj[i].text = t);

let obj = [ {"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}];
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

addAtoO(arr, obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` as you are using , & use it's index to get the value from `arr` array and create a new object with values from `obj` & `arr`

```js
let obj = [{
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

let output = obj.map(function(item, index) {
  return Object.assign({}, item, {
    text: arr[index]
  })

})

console.log(output)
```

Else you can also use `forEach` and mutate the original `obj` array

```js
let obj = [{
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

obj.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.text = arr[index]

})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` like this:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {"id": "1"},
  {"id": "2"},
  {"id": "3"}
]
const arr2 = ["a", "b", "c"];

const merge = (a1, a2) => a1.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, {text: a2[i]}));

console.log(merge(arr1, arr2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For more flexibility, i suggest to use a key for the function as well as parameter.

```js
const addTo = (objects, values, key) =>
        objects.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, { [key]: values[i] }));

console.log(addTo([{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }], ["a", "b", "c"], 'text'));
```

If you like to mutate the given objects, just remove the empty object from `Object.assign`.

```js
const addTo = (objects, values, key) =>
        objects.map((o, i) => Object.assign(o, { [key]: values[i] }));

var objects = [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }];

addTo(objects, ["a", "b", "c"], 'text');
console.log(objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make things complicated. Just use a `forEach`.

```js
let obj = [{
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

obj.forEach((object, index) => {
  object.text = arr[index]
})

console.log(obj)
```